# Pandas mixing up day and month after 7th row in data - How to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

My 'Date' column format is switching the days and months after row 7. It seems to be pulling in the dates in the format yyyy/dd/mm; however, I want my dates to be 'mm/dd/yyyy' but it keeps getting mixed up and I'm not sure how to fix this.

For example:

- Date
- 0   2019-02-01
- 1   2019-03-01
- 2   2019-04-01
- 3   2019-05-01
- 4   2019-06-01
- 5   2019-07-01
- 6   2019-08-01
- 7   2019-09-01
- 8   2019-01-10
- 9   2019-01-11

Here's what I'm doing:

```
#import the file from my computer
data = pd.ExcelFile(r'file on my computer')

#parse data
rates = data.parse("Sheet 1")

#print deminsions and glimpse
print(rates.shape)
rates.head(15)

#convert Date columns to desired format 
rates['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(rates['Date'], format = '%Y%d%m')

#check if it worked
rates.head(16)
```

it still shows the dates as the same as above.

Comment: Shouldn't your format be `%Y-%d-%m` rather than '%Y%d%m'? the `format` specifier lets the function know in which format the dates are present in the input file and not the format you want. You can use something like datetime.strftime if you choose to change the format later on.

Comment: _#convert Date columns to desired format_ That's not what the `format` argument to `pandas.to_datetime()` does, have you read the docs?

Comment: I made the change but it still didn't change anything. My file contains the date all in the same format in excel, for example: 02/01/2019 (dd/mm/yyy) throughout the entire column.

Comment: Don't open the file in Excel to check for the format, it does all weird stuff sometimes. Open with a text editor the sublime to check for the format and read it accordingly.

Comment: I re-saved the original file as a CSV and it worked! thanks for your help!